# Can we use [Operationcontract(isOneWay="true")] in WCF REST?

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

I want to call `rest` operation from jquery. I don't want to wait for the response, but instead,just confirm that it reached the server(status 202).

can I use `[operationContarct(isOneWay="true"]` in my IService ?

Is it as simple as calling any `$.ajax` to `[operationContract([webInvoked(method="...")`?
Or do I need to apply further configurations... or maybe this kind of behavior is only suitable for request that are represented in soap messages.

What are my options (emphasis on performance: client/server)?

Comment: Just because a WCF method has `IsOneWay=true` applied to it doesn't mean the caller isn't waiting for the call to be processed..... (it **will** wait - unless you have the async version of this call)

Comment: what do you mean by async version of this call ? xml body for the request that looks like soap <envelope... with corrsponding headers for the isOneWay attribute...or a  client proxy for that server? I hope i making any sense...

Comment: @marc_s maybe at crossed purposes here but IsOneWay=true means precisely that the client doesn't wait for a response. All it waits for is a TCP ACK that the packets were received - it doesn't wait for the message to be processed

Comment: @RichardBlewett: yes, that's what I meant - even with `IsOneWay=True`, the client still waits for an acknoledgement .... most folks believe the client returns immediately - not waiting for anything - but that's **NOT** the case.....

Comment: the acknowledgement is the http status 202 i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that oneway=true means that a 'void response object' will still be returned by the service when the method has processed, however it will not allow any fault exceptions to be returned to the caller.

Comment: but does it need additional configuration in web.config for the server, special format for the body request +addition headers , or is it just working as any regular  $.ajax()  call from  the client + the additional [operationContaract(IsOneWay="true")] attribute in wcf service and nothing more...